# Drupal: how can I remove the links from taxonomy terms?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I like the taxonomy terms in my nodes pages, but I don't want user being able to click on them. I just want to remove the links.

I'm trying to remove them from taxonomy module php files, but I cannot find them.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never want to edit a core module like taxonomy, as this makes it very complicated to upgrade your Drupal install. [See also](http://heyrocker.com/hack_core.jpg).

You can use [hook_link_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_link_alter/6) to alter/remove the links in your own module. Adding them back in as non-links is a little more complicated, but can be done in your node.tpl.php file with [example code](http://drupal.org/node/317172#comment-1046124).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [Display Suite module](http://drupal.org/project/ds) or some jQuery

```
jQuery(".taxonomy-term h2 a").each(function(){
var $t = jQuery(this);
$t.after($t.text());
$t.remove();
```

Thanks @Will and @Matt for this elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
jQuery(".views-field-field-categories >.field-content >a").removeAttr("href");
```

Comment: Pasting code without explanation doesn't help most users of SO probably running into the same issue. Could you elaborate on this so other people with similar issues might benefit from this answer, too. What does your code? In what file is it to be put? Maybe: are there any side effects or downsides you are aware of?

Comment: While this answer _may_ solve the question, it contains no explanation of how or why it does so.