# drupal 7 node page remove the term link?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drupal: how can I remove the links from taxonomy terms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943453/drupal-how-can-i-remove-the-links-from-taxonomy-terms)

i don't want to show the term  under the post content. when i using

```
hide($content['field_term']);
      print render($content);
```

but it doesn't work? why ? the term still under the post content.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need all that, simply go to `The manage display page` of your content type: `admin/structure/types/manage/page/display`

Then choose `<Hidden>` next to the terms field.

Comment: ok got it.if i want to use code to do that, how do i do? thank u

Comment: What you did should work `hide($content['field_term']);`? If you have created a new template for your theme, don't forget to **flush the cache**

Answer (score 0):

It is usually better to use the UI when you can. But there is also the possibility of changing templates. Trying to answer from memory I'd say you can change whether this is output in the node.tpl.php which your theme probably already has available and ready for changing.